# I can't print from Python IDLE in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, python-idle

Since upgrading to Windows 10 I can no longer print from the IDLE Python IDE. The "print to default printer" box comes up as usual, but nothing is sent to the print queue ... I checked in Devices & Printers.

Printing from other applications works fine.

Comment: I'm assuming it is a Python Windows-10 issue, since I can print fine from all other apps.

Comment: Python is a programming language. What "app" are you printing from? An IDE like PyCharm?

Comment: I used 'app' the way Windows does - it calls EVERYTHING an app. I'm using vanilla Python .. IDLE to be precise.  I normally use Ctrl-P to print either the Python program/script or the Python shell.  Since installing Windows-10, neither operation causes anything to be sent to the print queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirmed on my Win10 machine.  However for me, the problem is not with Win 10.  It is a stupid bug that I introduced in 2.7.11, 3.4.4, and 3.5.1.  I am assuming that you must have upgraded Python also.  You can test if you have the same cause by running `python -m idlelib` (or `idlelib.idle` on 2.7) in a console.  After IDLE starts, try to print and you should see a traceback ending with `NameError: name 'idleConf' is not defined`.

My apologies for the blunder.  I will fix this for future releases as soon as I finish improving the test so it would have caught this.

To fix it in the meanwhile, carefully edit `<python-dir>/Lib/idlelib/IOBinding.py`.  Move this line

```
from idlelib.configHandler import idleConf
```

from about line 530, after a `tkinter` import, to line 13, after an `askstring` import.  Remove the indent when you do so.