# Python 2.7.11, 3.4.4, 3.5.1 IDLE Print Window function doesn't work

Tags: python-idle

I was using Python 3.4 and used the Print Window menu item on the file menu often. Upgraded Python to version 3.5 and now that function is not working. I would click File > Print Window > Print to Default Printer and click OK. Nothing happens. I confirmed that my printer is working and that I can print from programs by printing from Notepad. I also printed from the browser. It's only IDLE that refuses to print. Is there a setting that I didn't set, or could this be a bug? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't print from Python IDLE in Windows 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35021370/i-cant-print-from-python-idle-in-windows-10)

Comment: I also gave the fix in my answer to the previous version of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug I accidentally introduced into the November releases and have since  reverted (fixed).  My apologies to all affected.

The fix in `idlelib/IOBinding.py` is to move the following line

```
from idlelib.configHandler import idleConf
```

from the current location, about line 525, near the bottom, to about line 7 and remove the indent.

Comment: Thanks! I will implement your solution!